# Pushing an object onto an array from inside an .on event

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, es6-promise

I have some csv data I need to parse into array of objects for an API I am building.

I am able to see that the parser I am using is working as expected this way:

```js
const csv = require('fast-csv')
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let results = [];

async function parseCSVFromCSV(_sourceCSVFilePath){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(_sourceCSVFilePath)
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on('error', error => reject(error)) 
    .on('data', row => {
      console.log(row);
      results.push(row);
    })
    resolve(results);
  })
}
```

so the `console.log(row)` prints out the parsed object as expected but the results object is empty.  I am needing this parsed data but no matter what I try I can't get results to populate with parsed csv.

Any guidance on what I a missing here?

Comment: When do you `resolve` the promise?

Comment: you should await parseCSVFromCSV call, until it gets data if it contains any, then you can read or change data structure

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I need to do:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

async function getData(){
    let arrOfObj = [];

    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'downloads', 'sampleData.csv'))
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on('error', error => console.error(error))
    .on('data', row => 
        {arrOfObj.push(row); 
        //console.log(row);
    })
    .on('end', rowCount => { printData(arrOfObj);  
    });
}

async function printData(_arrOfObj){
   console.log(_arrOfObj);
}

getData();
```

Basically the finished array will not be accessible expect inside of the `end` event.  This allows it be exposed to outside the event.  Hope this helps others that were needing to do this same thing.